# Find Lyapunov function of a autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

> Let $x_1(x), x_2(x), x_3(x)$ satisfy the system
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x_1' = -2x_1+x_2x_3 \\
> x_2' = x_1 - x_1x_3 \\
> x_3' = x_1x_2
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Construct a Lyapunov function to show that the origin is stable. Is the origin asymptotically stable?

I tried $V = x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + x^2_3$ and get $V' = -4x_1^2 + 4x_1x_2$, which isn't successful. A lot of my other tries would cause $V$ failed to be positive definite.

Comment: The obvious does not work. So as always you pass to the Jordan form.

Comment: The origin is not stable. You probably have a typo in the equations.

Comment: I checked and there are no typos.